# Is it possible to create a generic class with empty constructor in Java

Tags: java, generics, jvm

Is it possible to create a generic class with empty constructor?

To something like this:

```
 public class ArrayListGeneric1<T> {
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private T [] array;


    public ArrayListGeneric1() {
        capacity = 1;
        array =  Array.newInstance(T.getClass(), capacity); //Cannot get the class for T
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

I can only find solutions where we need to pass an element

Comment: You can have a no-arg constructor on a generic type. But you can't call `T.getClass()` on a generic type parameter `T`. The generic type parameter is not available at runtime.

Comment: If it wasn't possible to have a generic class with a no-args constructor, that would mean they would not have a default constructor if the class did not define any constructors, which I don't think makes much sense.

Comment: @Nexevis I've Updated the question for better clarity

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you Turner, my bad I was testing some possibilities and added that surpressWarning by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a generic class with empty constructor?

Sure, do it without a generic array, just like `ArrayList` does:

```
 public class ArrayListGeneric1<T> {
    private int capacity = 1;
    private int size = 0;
    private Object[] array = new Object[capacity];

    public ArrayListGeneric1() {}

    public T get(int i) {
      return (T) array[i];
    }

    public void set(int i, T element) {
      array[i] = element;
    }
}
```

---

You can actually do it with a generic array, if you make the type abstract, and subclass it when you create an instance:

```
  public abstract class ArrayListGeneric1<T> {
    private int capacity = 1;
    private int size = 0;
    private T[] array = Array.newInstance(getElementType(), capacity);

    public ArrayListGeneric1() {}   

    Class<?> getElementType() {
      ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      Type[] typeArgs = pt.getActualTypeArguments();

      // Will fail if it's not a class type.
      return (Class<?>) typeArgs[0];
    }
  // ...
}
```

Then:

```
ArrayListGeneric1<String> list = new ArrayListGeneric1<String>() {}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/fgJ5dl

Comment: Correct code (I think, didn't test it), but not the OP's question.  To reinforce, *no you can't create a `new T[]` in Java.*  The above answer is one typical way to work around this issue.

Comment: @markspace it answers "Is it possible to create a generic class with empty constructor?"

Comment: He edited his question, he changed it basically getting the type of `T` at runtime.

Comment: @markspace I answered before that edit, and have clarified which question I am answering.

Comment: Thank you Andy, Appreciated the time invested

Comment: @markspace you are right, but that was how I had the question initially, I Was not explicit enough to right it down as I wish. I later changed the title but I had already answers, which would be unfair for the people who already answered, so I changed the title back again to the original title and this is indeed the correct answer

Comment: @AndyTurner Andy, I'm sorry for the confusion created, my bad writting messed the the things a little but I've rollback the title to as it was and your answer is indeed correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem. `ArrayList` is a generic class with no-args constructor:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
List b = new ArrayList<>();
var c = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can find the exemplary implementation [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

Comment: Hi Andronicus, that's not my intention but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @Nelssen I literally answered your question: *Is it possible to create a generic class with empty constructor?*

Comment: You are right @Andronicus, the confusion was in my side, I asked something, but wanted to ask another thing related which was if it was possible to infer the generic type in an empty constructor. I changed the title, but later you guys had already answered and confusion was generated. I rollback the questions title and your answer is indeed correct, I've upvoted you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Given below is an example from Java OOTB class:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{

    private int size;

    public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        super();
        if (initialCapacity < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                               initialCapacity);
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
     */
    public ArrayList() {
        this(10);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
```